# How to iterate this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.ExamTemplateId, A.Id AS AnsweredTestId, AVG(B.Score) AS AvgScore, A.[Date]
FROM AnsweredTest AS A
INNER JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B ON (A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId)
WHERE A.StudentId = 'OPA-3DKCL2' AND A.ExamTemplateId = 1
GROUP BY A.Id, A.ExamTemplateId, A.[Date]
ORDER BY AvgScore DESC
```

Please check that I have a `WHERE` condition which receives a static number. The query result is:

EXAMPLE 1
[image]

EXAMPLE 2
[image]

And it is correct! But now, I'd like to show all the records from a ExamTemplate table. But now I don't know how can I accomplish that. I was thinking creating a function but I'm not sure, it's just an idea.

The final output which I'd like to receive is the union of last records:

```
1   1   0.7 2012-10-21 19:50:11.697
2   10  0.555555555555556   2012-10-22 18:58:24.163
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I've got highlighted with yellow color the rows which I'm interested. I set in the last query `TOP 1` because I want to get the highest average score by `ExamTemplateId`. And that's will be all.

[image]

Comment: can you post the desired output you need

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by "registries" here?

Comment: Sorry the correct terminology should be records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to replace the `A.ExamTemplateId = 1` with a list of values.  If so, then you should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT A.ExamTemplateId, 
  A.Id AS AnsweredTestId, 
  AVG(B.Score) AS AvgScore, 
  A.[Date]
FROM AnsweredTest AS A
INNER JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B 
  ON (A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId)
WHERE A.StudentId = 'OPA-3DKCL2' 
  AND A.ExamTemplateId IN (SELECT ExamTemplateId -- use a SELECT statement to get all template id
                           FROM ExamTemplateTable)
GROUP BY A.Id, A.ExamTemplateId, A.[Date]
ORDER BY AvgScore DESC
```

If you only want one value, then you can use something like this:

```
select ExamTemplateId,
    AnsweredTestId,
    AvgScore,
    [Date]
from 
(
  select ExamTemplateId,
    AnsweredTestId,
    AvgScore,
    [Date],
    row_number() over(partition by ExamTemplateId order by AvgScore) rn
  from
  (
    SELECT A.ExamTemplateId, 
      A.Id AS AnsweredTestId, 
      AVG(B.Score) AS AvgScore, 
      A.[Date]
    FROM AnsweredTest AS A
    INNER JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B 
      ON (A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId)
    WHERE A.StudentId = 'OPA-3DKCL2' 
      AND A.ExamTemplateId IN (SELECT ExamTemplateId -- use a SELECT statement to get all template id
                               FROM ExamTemplateTable)
    GROUP BY A.Id, A.ExamTemplateId, A.[Date]
  ) sc
) mx
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution. Just one more thing, please see my update

Comment: Do you only want one record or do you want two? If two, you can use `TOP 2`

Comment: Just one by ExamTemplate, in this case.. there are 3 which have Id = 2, so I get the record which has the highest score (second record). And by default the ExamTemplateId = 1 just have one record.

Answer (score 1):

Use partition by.

```
With t AS (
    SELECT A.ExamTemplateId, A.Id AS AnsweredTestId, AVG(B.Score) AS AvgScore, A.[Date] 
    FROM AnsweredTest AS A
    INNER JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B ON (A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId)
    WHERE A.StudentId = 'OPA-3DKCL2' --AND A.ExamTemplateId in (...)
    GROUP BY A.Id, A.ExamTemplateId, A.[Date]
)
, w AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExamTemplateId ORDER BY AvgScore DESC) rank
    FROM t 
)
SELECT * FROM w 
WHERE rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you were looking to see all students, but I guess you want over all exam templates - any reason you can't just remove the top 1 filter and take the exam template out of the where?
The averages would be computed per-exam template which is I think what you want.

```
SELECT A.ExamTemplateId, A.Id AS AnsweredTestId, AVG(B.Score) AS AvgScore, A.[Date]
FROM AnsweredTest AS A
INNER JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B ON (A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId)
WHERE A.StudentId = 'OPA-3DKCL2' 
GROUP BY A.Id, A.ExamTemplateId, A.[Date]
ORDER BY AvgScore DESC`
```